# When opening a new tab in Safari, the browser immediately changes page

Tags: macos, safari

I have an older iMac running macOS High Sierra. Safari is my browser of choice. Safari is set up so that when I open a new tab using the + sign shown below circled in red, it opens the Favorites page. See figure below:

[image]

Recently it has started going from Favorites page immediately to the one shown below with the following link open:

- [http://search.searchttv.com/?page=newtab&subid2=*sfnt*&ap=appfocus157&i_id=tv__sfnt_&source=bing-bb8-sfnt&uc=20190501&uid=839d16d3-94de-4a63-9a6a-c3f8e8742948](http://search.searchttv.com/?page=newtab&subid2=_sfnt_&ap=appfocus157&i_id=tv__sfnt_&source=bing-bb8-sfnt&uc=20190501&uid=839d16d3-94de-4a63-9a6a-c3f8e8742948)

How do I stop the new tab from going to the link above? Creating a new tab has worked fine for years. Now a new tab goes to the link given above.

[image]

Comment: Did you check if you have any extension installed that's causing it?

Comment: That sounds an awful lot like a browser hijack malware issue. I'd get a copy of MalwareBytes for the Mac and see what it finds. And try launching Safari in safe mode by launching it while holding the shift key, that disables a bunch of stuff that might be causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I have MalwareBytes running and i'll try safe mode next if needed.

Comment: Safe mode worked.  But now I'm at a loss of what to do next?